Are there disadvantages to parachains having block times higher or lower than 6 seconds? Any examples?
In the Polkadot ecosystem, parachains typically follow a 6-second block time to synchronize with the relay chain. However:
Are there disadvantages for parachains to use a higher or lower block time compared to the 6-second standard?
How would it affect performance, security, or compatibility with the relay chain?
Are there specific parachains that use a block time different from 6 seconds, and what are their reasons or use cases for doing so?
